# Temporarily hide notifications of other apps in Android

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I'm looking to manage the visible notifications of other apps. It looks like I can cancel notifications with a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). Is there a way to only do so temporarily, and then show them again at a later time?

Until now I've been turning on DND to do this, but that hides all notifications (or whatever the user has configured DND to do). I'd like to give them the choice of what app notifications to hide, temporarily.

Would [snoozeNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#snoozeNotification(java.lang.String,%20long)) do what I'm looking for? How would you then un-snooze a notification at a later time?

Comment: snooze sounds like what you're looking for.  Snooze takes a duration in ms, and will snooze it for that amount of time.  It does not appear to have a matching unsnooze to end that early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like calling snoozeNotification again with a short duration works to re-issue the notification!